# htaccess redirect URL related at mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a real estate site and I want to switch on/off offers, so the users/clients can open only the offers with field in MySQL "Status" = On. I'm not sure how to achieve this, buy .htaccess RewriteRule or the logic have to be in .php file or mixture of both. Currently .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*).css$  style.css
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/img/$ ./img/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/pic/$ ./pic/
RewriteRule ^.+-([0-9]+)$ offer.php?offer=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
RewriteRule ^\недвижимости$ /sale.php?top=yes&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^\продажа$ /sale.php [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of rewriting htaccess files, nor renaming/moving files around for access control.  I would probably take one of two approaches.  One would be to have the links go to a PHP file that redirects (or not, based on the SQL query) to a file, or, two, reads the file (or not) and downloads it.

Have your htaccess file rewrite xxx.jpg to mypic.php?file=xxx.jpg.  mypic.jpg checks the database and (your option) redirects to the file, or reads the file and downloads it.  The latter approach has the advantage of a) not exposing the location of the files, and b) not enabling image caching.  If the requested file is not available, you can return file not found, or some other helpful error message.

If you really want to alter the files to make them inaccessible, change the protection to unreadable (with respect to the web server), if the file is to be disabled.  Don't try to do it with name magic.